# While importing 'myapp.app' an import error was raised

Tags: flask

I'm building a flask application, located in a subdirectory within my project called `myapp`. Running `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT myapp.app:app` works fine, no errors, regardless of what FLASK_APP is set to. When I try to use Flask's CLI, however, it fails to find my app (reasonable), but when I set FLASK_APP to `myapp.app.`, it appears to be doubling up the import path, resulting in an import error:

```
FLASK_APP=myapp.app flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'myapp.app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'myapp.myapp.app', an ImportError was raised.
```

How can I solve this? Is this a bug in Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `__init__.py` in my project directory that was causing this.

---

I dug into the source code of flask in `cli.py` and found the following code in `prepare_import`:

```
    # move up until outside package structure (no __init__.py)
    while True:
        path, name = os.path.split(path)
        module_name.append(name)

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, "__init__.py")):
            break
```

Because I had an `__init__.py` in my project directory (also called myapp), this made flask try to import `myapp.app` from the ancestor of my project, resulting in `myapp.myapp.app`.